# How to implement seting up ssh tunneling to port... here?

Tags: linux, perl, ssh, cgi

I am doing my hw on this page: https://www.isi.deterlab.net/file.php?file=/share/shared/Softwareexploitsexercise/index.html#dassign

In the second task, I don't really know how to do the following:

> If you have set up ssh tunneling to port 80 via local port 8118 (a
>   good idea), the memo application can be accessed at
>   http://localhost:8118/cgi-bin/memo.cgi

How to set up ssh tunneling to port 80 via local port 8118? Is that certain command in terminal? Could you tell me how to do? The whole operation should be done in shell because it is on certain platform.

Comment: This is off-topic for StackOverflow.  It isn't really on-topic on any StackExchange site because we don't do homework for you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ssh feature is called port forwarding.

Local port forwarding listens to the port on local machine and forwards it via the connection to specified destination:

```
ssh -L 8118:localhost:80 ssh-server
```

In the example it forwards the port from client machine to localhost of the remote server but you can specify any destination you want. I assume the http server runs on that server.

Remote forwarding does the opposite, i.e. listens on port on remote server and forwards via ssh to specified destination:

```
ssh -R 8118:localhost:80 ssh-server
```

Again, it doesn't have to be localhost. It can forward the port 8118 on ssh-server to any destination accessible from the client machine.

Both forwardings are useful when the service is not directly accessible from the remote destination, either because of firewall, visibility or simply the service running on localhost only.

Comment: Could you tell me what ssh-server is in my case? And what is the relationship with cgi file in my question?